# WPF Flat Repeat Button (ToolBar look)

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I'm trying to give the `RepeatButton` the flat look w/o overriding the `ControlTemplate`. With the regular `Button` you can do the following (but not with the `RepeatButton`):

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">...
```

Is there something similar for the `RepeatButton` or for `ButtonBase`? I'm assuming no because if you put a `RepeatButton` in a `ToolBar` is does not get a flat look.

Is there a better way to give the `RepeatButton` a flat look other than overriding the `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: Have you tried styles ?

Comment: For my situation that's what I ended up doing (Style that sets the Template) but I was hoping to somehow make use of an existing style to reduce duplication. I believe Button and RepeatButton subclass ButtonBase so would have been great if the ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey targeted ButtonBase instead of Button.

Comment: @KornMuffin Could you maybe answer this question with your style?

Comment: Added Style created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what came up with for a flat RepeatButton Style with a Path as content:

```
<Style x:Key="RepeatButtonFlat" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" Height="14" Width="14">
                    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="2"
                          Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Sample usage:

```
<RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Content="M0,0 L1,0 .5,-.5 Z"/>
```